# How to avoid duplicate tap on button on Tableview with RxDataSources

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rxdatasources

I have a table view with RxDataSources on which cell items got a remove icon. when cells get dequeued and click on that remove icon, all the previous click events get triggered, thus duplicate tap.
Item cell :

```
 removeImageView.rx.tap().map { _ in indexPath } 
            .bind(to: viewModel.onRemoveItem).disposed(by: cellDisposeBag)
```

Cell viewmodel:

```
let onRemoveItem = PublishSubject<IndexPath>()
```

View controller view model where the cell and ViewModel get bound:

```
 let vm = ItemViewModel(with: item)
            vm.onRemoveItem.bind(to: self.onRemoveItem).disposed(by: self.rx.disposeBag)

            return SectionItem.item(viewModel: vm)
```

View Controller:

```
let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<SectionItem>(configureCell: { dataSource, tableView, indexPath, item in
    switch item {
    case .item(let viewModel):
        let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: itemtIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ItemCell)!
        cell.bind(to: viewModel, at: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}, titleForHeaderInSection: { dataSource, index in
    let section = dataSource[index]
    return section.title
}  )

output?.items
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
    .disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

output?.onRemoveCartIemTapped.distinctUntilChanged() 
    .skip(1)
    .distinctUntilChanged().drive(onNext: { [weak self] (indexPath) in
    print("onRemoveCartIemTapped" + String(indexPath.item))
}).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

Console debug:

```
onRemoveCartIemTapped0
onRemoveCartIemTapped3
onRemoveCartIemTapped1
onRemoveCartIemTapped4
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a sample project for this? I'd like to help you out on this. This should be pretty easy but I usually use the normal implementation of delegates and datasource methods of tableView in my ViewModel without using RxSwift's extensions (but using RxSwift in the entire project, not just in tableViews).

Comment: Are you disposing `cellDisposeBag` in the cell's `prepareForReuse` method?  If the cells are being reused without the subscriptions being disposed then it could cause this kind of behaviour.

Comment: no i don't use prepareForReuse at all. how can i do that even though i  have cell dispose when button tapped

Comment: @Paul I fixed it, thank you :). post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the `UITableView` reusing the cell. To avoid having multiple subscriptions, you can override the cell's `prepareForReuse()` method and ensure any existing subscriptions are disposed.

I usually declare the `DisposeBag` as a var and then assign a new `DisposeBag` to it in `prepareForReuse()`.  When the `DisposeBag` is deinited it will dispose all of the subscriptions it contains.  Something like:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    cellDisposeBag = DisposeBag()
}
```

Comment: _When the `DisposeBag` is deinited_ <-- when does that happen?

Comment: @mfaani it gets deinited when you reassign a new DisposeBag to the variable, as there are no references in memory pointing to the original one anymore.